# Error publishing an V2 Azure Function .Net Core

Tags: azure, .net-framework, publishing

I've created an Azure Functions project in .Net Core and just add a HttpTrigger function. When I try to publish it (to an exiting function or a new one), I get an error.

2>The "UserAgentVersion" parameter is not supported by the "ZipDeployTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

2>The "ZipDeployTask" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

I've also created a project in .Net Standard and I am able to publish it successfully. I am only getting the error for V2 functions.

Comment: Please see this post for details https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52a71576-76e8-48dc-bbf3-6a80c51be23d/error-publishing-an-v2-azure-function-from-vs-2019?forum=AzureFunctions I've tried again a week after and it worked.

Comment: the solution at the link says that "it just started magically working" I have not detected any magic thus far on my side

Comment: i finally got some magic, and it started working after I removed the publish profile and re-added it a few times :\